# Upload image to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, image, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I see SQL Server 2008 has an image field type, I'm looking to use the VS 2010 FileUpload control (c#) to let users load a logo next to their profile on our database, can anyone give me a starter on how to do this?

thanks again

Comment: The `IMAGE` datatype has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 - use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead

Comment: Cool, is it best to save just the path to a saved image or is it ok to save the image itself?

Comment: Added an answer for that question you asked here in your comment - quite a lengthy issue! Gets asked frequently here, too. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a really good paper by Microsoft Research called [To Blob or Not To Blob](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525) that discusses in great detail whether or not to store the actual data in your database table, or just a path to a file on disk.

Their conclusion after a large number of performance tests and analysis is this:

- if your pictures or document are typically below 256K in size, storing them in a database VARBINARY column is more efficient
- if your pictures or document are typically over 1 MB in size, storing them in the filesystem is more efficient (and with SQL Server 2008's FILESTREAM attribute, they're still under transactional control and part of the database)
- in between those two, it's a bit of a toss-up depending on your use

If you decide to put your pictures into a SQL Server table, I would strongly recommend using a separate table for storing those pictures - do not store the employee foto in the employee table - keep them in a separate table. That way, the Employee table can stay lean and mean and very efficient, assuming you don't always need to select the employee foto, too, as part of your queries.

For filegroups, check out [Files and Filegroup Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx) for an intro. Basically, you would either create your database with a separate filegroup for large data structures right from the beginning, or add an additional filegroup later. Let's call it "LARGE_DATA".

Now, whenever you have a new table to create which needs to store VARCHAR(MAX) or VARBINARY(MAX) columns, you can specify this file group for the large data:

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
     (....... define the fields here ......)
     ON Data                   -- the basic "Data" filegroup for the regular data
     TEXTIMAGE_ON LARGE_DATA   -- the filegroup for large chunks of data
```

Check out the MSDN intro on filegroups, and play around with it!